# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Open Data's [second](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/election/2) election has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated.

[image: nicolas-raoul] [image: pluviophile]

Please also join me in thanking the following two users, who'll be stepping down from their positions as moderators:

[image: patrick-hoefler]  [image: philshem]

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Patrick and philshem for your work until now!

I will try to do my best!

Pluviophile, looking forward to collaborating with you.

Answer (score 5):

@Patrick and @philshem

Heartfelt thanks for all the time and attention you gave to **Open Data**

@Nicolas Raoul I’m looking forward to working with you, too.